# can ConstraintLayout help to flow the right side item to next line?

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

Having a textView alight to left edge, its width could grow. Having some other textView in its right align in single line.

When the left `textView` width grows, would like the right textView to be pushed down to next line:

```
[AAA]  [BBB]
```

when left one width grows:

```
[AAA AAA AAA AAA AAA]

[BBB]
```

Thought seeing some sample using `ConstraintLayout` to automatically push the right side item to next line down, but couldnt find any.

It is doable with `ContraintLayOut`, or anyone knows some sample to do it?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874011/constraintlayout-flow-helper-example/56106542#56106542 if you want to use new Flow virtual layout with ConstraintLayout to achieve this

Comment: You'd check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122205/how-to-make-buttons-change-position-according-to-the-screen-size-and-or-font-siz/76168684#76168684)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Update*: The answer below is still valid, but as of *ConstraintLayout* 2.0 it may be better to use the [*Flow*](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) helper. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56106542/6287910) Stack Overflow answer for an example.

---

AFAIK, flowing views from one line to the next is not something that `ConstraintLayout` can do. It is, however, something that `FlexboxLayout` can do very easily.

[Here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html) is an initial introduction to the technology. There are also a few good apps on the Play store to play around with the layout.

> FlexboxLayout can be interpreted as an advanced LinearLayout because both layouts align their child views sequentially. The significant difference between LinearLayout and FlexboxLayout is that FlexboxLayout has a feature for wrapping.

Comment: Thanks Cheticamp for sharing the FlexboxLayout! But would really like to know how to use ConstrainLayout for it.

Comment: @lannyf No problem. However, I don't think that you will get the answer you are looking for. The fact that FlexboxLayout was open sourced at the same time ConstraintLayout was released and was touted for its ability to wrap views (the feature you are looking for in ConstraintLayout) leads me to believe that ConstraintLayout does not have that particular capability.

Comment: Constraint Layout 2.0 now has Flow helper. As of now, it's in 2.0.0-alpha1.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup` like this

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaaaa"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bbbbbb"/>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cccccccc"/>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fffffffff"/>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hhhhhhh"/>
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="trtr"/>
    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

[see more here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know I am pretty late to the party but to anyone who's still subscribed to this question, as of today `ConstraintLayout` 2.0 (just launched in beta1) supports a new `ConstraintHelper` called `Flow` using which your specific requirement can be fulfilled in `ConstraintLayout`.

[Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/helper/Flow)

[The following are the release notes for beta1](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/04/constraintlayout-200-alpha-5.html)

Answer (score -1):

after searching around and conclusion is ConstraintLayout is to flatten the view hierarchy of the layouts to avoid nesting, to optimize the view hierarchy. 
So as @Cheticamp pointed out "ConstraintLayout does not have that particular capability". So closing this question.