# How to manage the position of TextViews dynamically when screen size changes

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-linearlayout

I have two textviews in one horizontal layout, the first is normal text and the second is clickable with a different color.

**XML**

```
   <!--inside rootlayout..-->

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:maxLines="2"
          android:text="By clicking sign up, you agree to our "
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <TextView
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:text="terms and conditions"
          android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:clickable="true"/>

      </LinearLayout>
```

And It gives me a great look on large screens (4.7 inch and above),
 but when the screen size is lower, the second textview gets weird.! I want it to automatically position itself below the first textview or to make their parent layout orientation vertical..!!

here's how it looks.!

[image]

---

**Update #1**

why the `ForegroundColorSpan` won't change!? it always shows blue or black no matter what color resources I set.!??

```
private void handleTermsConditions() { 
    SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(termsTxt.getText());
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 38, 58, 0);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(RegistrationActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary);
    ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(color);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(fcs, termsTxt.getText().length() - 20, termsTxt.getText().length(),
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View widget) {
        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
      }
    };

    stringBuilder.setSpan(clickableSpan, 38, 58, Spanned.SPAN_POINT_MARK); 
    termsTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    termsTxt.setText(stringBuilder);
  }
```

Comment: I think that it happens automatically... It depends on space, if it has enough space so it will be like in first screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your requirement you don't have to use 2 text views for this you can place a **spannable** string builder on just 1 text and put clickable as well as color property and you are done.

**Code:**

```
 TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tvSample);
    SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder  =new SpannableStringBuilder(textView.getText());
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),textView.getText().length()-20,textView.getText().length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    stringBuilder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    },textView.getText().length()-20,textView.getText().length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  textView.setText(stringBuilder);
```

Here is [example](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html) of putting different spans on text view

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981307/how-to-set-multiple-spans-on-a-textviews-text-on-the-same-partial-text) is how to set two spans on single text view

Comment: why the `ForegroundColorSpan` won't change? I used a color from my res file but it always shows blue? here's the code `int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);ForegroundColorSpan fcs  =new ForegroundColorSpan(color);stringBuilder.setSpan(fcs,termsTxt.getText().length()-20,termsTxt.getText().length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

Comment: int color  = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);

Comment: still the same..! I posted the full code in Update #1.  please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

The same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699693/can-constraintlayout-help-to-flow-the-right-side-item-to-next-line) or from [the original document](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

Get the height and width of your device and use the values to decide whether to set screen to portrait or not:

```
if ((height == <value>) && (width == <value>)) {
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

*Feel free to modify as required in your activity

Answer (score 1):

You can set TextView Font size or width according to screen size using value folder. [Try like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **most easy way** Android Spannable property for doing this. and by that way you can do this work by single textview and can manage your click events.

Here is code for doing this.

```
public void setHighLightedText(TextView textView, String textToHighlight) {
    String tvt = textView.getText().toString();
    int ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, 0);

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
 //            here you do all stuff
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setColor(0xff0000ff);
            ds.setUnderlineText(true);
 // Here you can put your style on textview.
        }
    };

    SpannableString wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(textView.getText());

    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < tvt.length() && ofe != -1; ofs = ofe + 1) {
        ofe = tvt.indexOf(textToHighlight, ofs);
        if (ofe == -1)
            break;
        else {
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(clickableSpan, ofe, ofe + textToHighlight.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            textView.setText(wordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

You can see `onClick` method in it. there you can set click or use callback if you put this code in Utility class.

Bonus

***Also this is the right way to do this.***

Answer (score 0):

Either use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

**OR**

Try autoSizeText

```
<TextView
.......
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
................................../>
```

Here is something about it on android developer [site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html)