# Responsive layout for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make the buttons in my activity to change orientation according to its layout size. For tablets, It need to show two buttons in a row with same size, and for small screen mobiles one stretched width button per row.  Is it possible with Android ? How can I do it?

[image: Android Responsive Layout]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524010/can-we-make-one-layout-type-for-all-screen-size/47524265#47524265) answer.

Comment: create different layout for portrait and landscape mode

Comment: Is there a way without creating multiple layouts ? 
Can I use constraint layout to do so?

Comment: @YesudassMoses yes, without creating multiple layout..you can do.

Comment: See my post it will help you

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being down voted. Weird.

Comment: Thanks for all down votes :) :P keep downvoting

Answer (score 2):

You have to use in different layout folder in your android resouce folder

like

```
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
```

**layout-sw720dp**

layout-sw720dp is represented in 10 inch Tab

**layout-sw600dp**

layout-sw600dp is represented in 7 inch Tab

**layout-sw480dp**

layout-sw480dp is represented in 4.5 and above inch mobiles

**layout-sw320dp**

layout-sw320dp is represented in below 4.5 inch mobiles

> Note, And also follow your should use different **dimens** files

Like

```
values-sw320dp
values-sw480dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
```

for more info:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

[Different values folders in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android)

Comment: If you were to go down this path, I would suggest you use layout merging. I would create just one layout for the activity/fragment and then a merge layout just for the buttons container. Then create a bunch of buttons containers to deal with all possible sizes. It's not ideal but better than duplicating a large layout just because of a few buttons. https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: Yes, in this cause also I told, manage with different type of dimens files

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) (made by Google). If you're familiar with CSS Flexbox, you should feel at home with this.

EDIT: Another option, if you're using a RecyclerView, is to use the StaggeredGridLayoutManager. It won't automatically do what you want, however, you can get the screen size and then calculate how many columns you'd like. I'd try the flexbox one first, but I've done something similar with the staggered one.

Comment: Why the down vote? It seems like a great use case for it.

Comment: Can I achieve samething using built-in layouts ? Eg: Constraint Layout ?

Comment: I just edited my answer to include a second idea. If you intend to have this scroll, using the StaggeredGridLayoutManager with the RecyclerView and dynamically setting the column count could achieve the desired result. Just make sure all items are the same height.

Comment: To answer your question about the ConstraintView, I'm not sure. However, it seems that it is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699693/can-constraintlayout-help-to-flow-the-right-side-item-to-next-line

Comment: Is FlexBoxLayout heavy ? 
I want to keep my app slim with minimum 3rd party controls.

Comment: Not sure, but it obviously will be doing some calculations. I'd suggest it's worth trying. How many buttons are you putting on the screen? My biggest concern is that it appears to be an early version, but this is something made by Google so it's probably not really buggy. You can add it to your project in the same way you'd add constraint layout; in your build.gradle file.