# Can I use a Flow helper with RadioButtons?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I found the following post on SO regarding constraint layout flow helpers [ConstraintLayout Flow helper example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874011/constraintlayout-flow-helper-example) and wondered if they could be used with radio buttons.

I can find little about using flow helpers anywhere.

I tried adding the following to my layout inside the RadioGroup.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="radioButton, radioButton2, radioButton3"
        app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_verticalBias="0"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

When I try to run the app I get the following errors:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\AndroidProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:158: error: attribute flow_horizontalBias (aka com.domain.myapp:flow_horizontalBias) not found.
C:\AndroidProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:158: error: attribute flow_horizontalGap (aka com.domain.myapp:flow_horizontalGap) not found.
C:\AndroidProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:158: error: attribute flow_horizontalStyle (aka com.domain.myapp:flow_horizontalStyle) not found.
C:\AndroidProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:158: error: attribute flow_verticalBias (aka com.domain.myapp:flow_verticalBias) not found.
C:\AndroidProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:158: error: attribute flow_wrapMode (aka com.domain.myapp:flow_wrapMode) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha5` in gradle

Refer [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow)

Comment: Thanks. That gets rid of the errors. It doesn't seem to wrap the radio buttons, so I'm not sure if that means I can't use Flow with radio buttons or there's something else I need to do with my layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `ConstraintLayout` (and `Flow`) to arrange `RadioButton`, but you have to use a ConstraintLayout aware RadioGroup widget to manage `RadioButton` widgets.

Please visit https://github.com/samlu/ConstraintRadioGroup.
The `blRadioGroup` widget should be what you are looking for.