# Responsive imageview positioning

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design

I have a list item that contains an image (red) and another layout (blue)
Normally, the layout would be the first one, but the black layout's width depends on user configurations, so it may not fit the whole content.
I thought about making it a Linear Layout and changing the orientation depending on its width, but i read somewhere its possible to do such things with layout only (maybe constraint layouts).
Is it possible to achieve this result using only "layout responsiveness", or do i have to input some code also?

[image: layout]

Comment: It depends by the condition to use 1 or 2. How do you test if it fits the whole content?

Comment: Red and blue layout have a fixed width, and black depends on column count. If red + blue fits on black, then it should be displayed horizontally, if not, vertically.

Comment: Maybe a ConstraintLayout with a Flow helper is a good idea? Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874011/constraintlayout-flow-helper-example)

Comment: I think thats exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.